# Whats the difference between defining an object and set it's properties in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm forking a small library and making it object oriented in JS, everything went good until a object I was sending was not being treated correctly.
If I do this:

```
var foo = {};
foo.bar = barbar; //barbar is a variable
foo.bar2 = barbar2 //barbar2 is also a variable
//more stuff
```

The object works, however if I do this:

```
var foo = { bar : barbar, 'bar2': barbar2 /*more stuff*/ }
```

The library does not recognize the object properly.

I discovered this was the cause of the weird errors I was having after 3 hours of debugging and I still can't believe that was the cause.
Someone has any idea about why this happens? I need to dynamically create objects in the future and I would prefer the second method...

Edit:

I'm using the object to pass information to another function of what to draw in a canvas, for example:

```
var test = {};//
test.init_x = 0; // all this works no matter what method I use to set them
test.init_y = 0;
test.sourceFile = 'img/tiles.png';
test.tileWidth = 16;
test.tileHeight = 16; //still works
test.arrayTiles = array; // this is a very large array of numbers
// The above only works if its defined this way, i.e. not by test = {arrayTiles:array};
```

Sample code, this is what I'm doing to create the objects:

```
var test = {}
test.init_x = 0;
test.init_y = 0;
test.sourceFile = 'img/map/grid_tiles.png';
test.tileWidth = 16;
test.tileHeight = 16;
test.tile_offset_x = 1;
test.tile_offset_y = 1;
test.sourceTileCounts = 4096;
test.sourceTileAccross = 64;
test.tilesWide = 64;
test.tilesHigh = 64;
test.tilesArray = [];//large numbers array
test.physicsArray = phys;
test.zoneTilesWide = 8;
test.zoneTilesHigh = 8;
test.mapTiles = [];//large numbers array
test.decoration = [];//large numbers array
test.tilesArray = makeMapTilesArray(test.mapTiles, test.decoration);
```

The above does work, but the next snippet doesn't:

```
function Map(map,tiles,decor,phys,tileSizeW,tileSizeH,totalTiles,tilesPerRow,tilesW,tilesH,zoneW,zoneH){//map
    this.mapTiles           = tiles;
    this.decoration         = decor;
    this.tilesArray         = [];
    this.physicsArray       = phys;
    this.canvas             = 0;
    this.ctx                = 0;
    this.init_x             = 0;
    this.init_y             = 0;
    this.sourceFile         = 'img/map/'+map+'.png';
    this.tileWidth          = tileSizeW;
    this.tileHeight         = tileSizeH;
    this.tile_offset_x      = 1;
    this.tile_ofset_y       = 1;
    this.sourceTileCounts   = totalTiles;
    this.sourceTileAcross   = tilesPerRow;
    this.tilesWide          = tilesW;
    this.tilesHigh          = tilesH;
    this.zoneTilesWide      = zoneW;
    this.zoneTilesHigh      = zoneH;
    this.tilesArray = makeMapTilesArray(tiles, decor);//this function does some byte shifting
}
var test = new Map('grid_tiles',mapTiles,decoration,physicsArray,16,16,4096,64,64,64,8,8);
```

Why it doesn't work? What could the library be doing for both of this to **not** be equal?

Comment: More detail, please.  What is "more stuff"?  What do you mean "does not recognize the object properly"?

Comment: If `barbar` and `barbar2` are defined, then both of your methods work just fine so there must be something else going on that you are not showing us.  Also, please be careful with terminology.  What you are defining is an object, not an array.

Comment: @RayToal Simply put more properties definitions, and by not recognizing the object, well it's a bit complicated, I'll update my post in a moment.

Comment: What error you are getting?
Also you should use a common standard for all the objects insted what you have done in var foo = { bar : barbar, 'bar2': barbar2 /*more stuff*/ }

Comment: @DigvijayYadav I do not get any syntax error if that's what your thinking, its the library doing different things if use method 1 and method 2 for the same process.
And by the bar and 'bar2' I tried to say that I tried declaring all values in those 2 ways.

Comment: Here when you do not use the quotes on the right hand side the browser or may be the library you are using, is interpreting then to be variables not the string, which are not defined. So its better to use quotes on the right hand side.

Comment: I tried with and without quotes, no matter what only setting the properties via `foo.bar = foobar;` works, not by directly creating the object with `var foo = {bar:foobar}`

Comment: @nyanko could you post a complete code sample?
`var foo = {bar: [1,2,3]};` is perfectly valid. Likewise, `var foo = [1,2,3], bar = {foo: foo};` is valid. In this case, you would have an object `bar` where `bar.foo` is `[1,2,3]`.

Comment: I know its technically the same, but the library is handling it differently, I want to know how can you differentiate how an object was created since the library is clearly doing so.